# Is $L^p(\Omega)$ separable over Lebesgue measure.

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, separable-spaces

I was wondering if $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is separable when $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measure space. I know $L^p(X)$ is separable, provided $X$ is a separable measure space. Consequently, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Borel measure is a separable measure space, $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is separable if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel measure space. It seems that $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not separable over Lebesgue measure space. Is it true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! What is the difference of $L^p$ with Borel measure and Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @copper.hat I think $L^p$ space with Lebesgue measure is bigger than $L^p$ space with Borel measure. Is it true that $L^p$ space with Lebesgue measure is separable.

Comment: Remember that $L^{p}$ consists of equivalence classes rather then actual measurable functions. The two $L^{p}$'s you are taking about are one and the same!. Every Lebesgue measurable function is almost everywhere equal to a Borel measurable function.

Comment: Also, it is straightforward to show that the continuous functions (that lie in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$) are dense in either space, and it is also straightforward to construct a countable set of simple functions that are dense in the continuous functions. Hence both are separable.